# Click-event not triggering inside a Plotly subplot within Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, subplot, r-plotly, mouseclick-event

I'm creating a [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) app with 2 different tabs. Each of them has a couple of [plotly](/questions/tagged/plotly) plots. I want the plots to only react to the *plotly_click* events from the correspondent tab. My problem comes when instead of having separated plots, I want one of them to be part of a subplot.

To do so, I have added the *source* parameter to the plots in order to distinguish which plot is the one that has been clicked. When the plots are individual plots (not inside a subplot) works nicely, but if I try to put one of them inside a compound subplot, no more events related to that plot seem to be triggered.

The working code is something like this:

```r
ui <- navbarPage("",  
    tabPanel("Tab1",
        plotlyOutput("tab1plot1"),
        plotlyOutput("tab1plot2")
    ),
    tabPanel("Tab2",
        plotlyOutput("tab2plot1"),
        plotlyOutput("tab2plot2")
    )
)
```

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$tab1plot1 <- renderPlotly({
        plot_ly(x = dates, y = y, source = "tab1plot1", ...)
    })

    output$tab1plot2 <- renderPlotly({
        click <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "tab1plot1")
        if (!is.null(click)) {
            # process click
            plot_ly(x = dates, y = processedY, ...)
        }
        else { NULL }
    })

    output$tab2plot1 <- renderPlotly({
        plot_ly(source = "tab2plot1", ...)
    })

    output$tab2plot2 <- renderPlotly({
        click <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "tab2plot1")
        if (!is.null(click)) {
            # process click ...
        }
        else { ... }
    })
```

This works as expected, but the problem comes when I try to change the *tab1plot1* for a compound subplot as this:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$tab1plot1 <- renderPlotly({
        p1 <- plot_ly(x = dates, y = y, source = "tab1plot1", ...)
        p2 <- plot_ly( ... )
        subplot(p1, p2, nrows = 2, shareX = TRUE)
    })

   ...
}
```

If I do so, the *plotly_click* event is never triggered and so the *tab1plot2* is never changed. In fact, I get a log message: 
"Warning: Can only have one: source
Warning: The 'plotly_click' event tied a source ID of 'main' is not registered. In order to obtain this event data, please add `event_register(p, 'plotly_click')` to the plot (`p`) that you wish to obtain event data from."

Am I missing something or plotly just doesn't support the *source* attribute inside a subplot?

Comment: I don't have a proper answer to your question (regarding the support), but I have experienced the same sort of issue that you have. The solution to me was to register events from all the plots (in your case `p1` and `p2`) and define two variables to grab the events... **However**, the variable for the 2nd plot was getting __all the events__, including for the 1st plot.

Comment: BTW, if you have multiple tabs in your app, you may be interested in using [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)

Answer (score 1):

Plotly does support `source` with `subplot`; you just have to specify the same source ID for all the plots within that subplot. One way that will work is:

```
output$tab1plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    p1 <- plot_ly(x = dates, y = y, ...)
    p2 <- plot_ly( ... )
    s <- subplot(p1, p2, nrows = 2, shareX = TRUE)
    s$x$source <- "tab1plot1"
    s
})
```

Reference: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1504